# In CakePHP 3.6 Layout I do not load the views

Tags: layout, cakephp-3.0

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title><?= h($this->fetch('title')) ?></title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<!-- Include external files and scripts here (See HTML helper for more info.) -->


 <?php
    echo $this->fetch('meta');
    echo $this->fetch('css');
    echo $this->fetch('script');
    ?>
</head>
<body>

<!-- If you'd like some sort of menu to
show up on all of your views, include it here -->
<div id="header">
    <div id="menu">...</div>
</div>

<!-- Here's where I want my views to be displayed -->
<?= $this->fetch('content') ?>

<!-- Add a footer to each displayed page -->
<div id="footer">...</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Hi,

reading the documentation of CakePHP 3.6 tells me that in the Layout the content is loaded in: `<?= $this->fetch('content') ?>`

In CakePHP 3.6 the views are saved in src/Template

My view:   `src/Template/Casa/casa.ctp`

This way if I create a view called for example casa.ctp with its controller CasaController.php for this view to be seen in the Layout, I should call it this way: `<?= $this->fetch('casa') ?>`

This is so? because it's like I'm trying it but it does not work for me, it does not load anything, but it does not give me any mistakes either.

regards

Comment: if you created a `casaController` with a `casa()` action and a `casa.ctp` view then it all should work (no need to fetch 'casa') . When you say "it does not load anything" what exactly do you mean? A blank page? An empty layout? Do you have debug enabled? Did you go to right url (i.e. `servername/casa/casa`)? Did you check your error log?

Comment: When I say that it does not load anything I mean that it loads an empty design, since the structure of the Layout and the styles load it, but it does not load the HTML of casa if I go to casa/casa it loads it as from the Layout and the log it does not show any error.

Comment: sorry for the dumb question but does `casa.ctp` contain anything?

Comment: Yes a foreach that points to a Model and the foreach that works and shows content because I have tried it in pure PHP, I also put a <? = hello word; ?> just in case.

Comment: Ok I have advanced something if I put `<?= $this->fetch('content') ?>` and I will servername/casa/casa then if it shows the content but if I go to servername directly it does not load it, how do I do it so I loaded it by default?

Comment: so you are telling that the problem was just in the url? You were pointing to `http://servername` instead of  `http://servername/casa/casa`? And now you want `http://servername` to show `casa/casa`? If so you can do with routing. See the [**manual**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#quick-tour). The beginning of the paragraph explain exactly your case

Comment: Yes, I realized, thank you

Answer (score 0):

you need a casa action in your CasaController.

```
class CasaController extends AppController
{

    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
    }

    public function casa()
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: I already have created the public function casa() in CasaController